Understanding the difference in the ideas of standard deviation and coefficient of variation
Question
I am a little bit confused as to why we need a coefficient of variation to understand and compare the "variability" of two data sets. Suppose we have the following two data sets:
A: 1,2,3,4,5
B: 100001,100002,100003,100004,100005
The mean is 3 and 100003, and the standard deviation is the same, which makes complete sense to me as the data sets are consecutive in nature. But clearly, their coefficient of variations is different, thus "variability" Which quantity does this "variability" correspond to? What exactly does this coefficient of variation signify?
Thoughts
What I can observe is that though 100001 is 2 less than 100003, it's approximately 99 percent of 100003, while 1 is approximately 33 percent of 3. So, does this mean 100001 is more "similar" to 100003 than 1 is to 3? Is this what the coefficient of variation signifies?

The coefficient of variation may not be meaningful for interval scales. This site does a pretty good job of explaining the difference between interval and ratio scales. https://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1089/

Well, just look at your sets.  For each, $\sigma\approx 1.58$ but a shift of $1.58$ makes a big difference in the first set, and much less in the second. Assuming this is data for which the scale matters.  The coefficient of variation captures that.  Of course, if you have $\sigma, \mu$ then you don't need to separately compute the coefficient of variation.

The coefficient of variation does not mean much if $0$ is an arbitrary point rather than something special or meaningful, as shown by your example.  It is also difficult to interpret if values can be both positive and negative.  But the coefficient of variation is scale-free (e.g. it does not matter whether your measurements are in seconds or weeks), which may be useful in some cases.
